# CakePHP 3.8 - How to access public path to webroot in view?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Migrating from 2.3.x to 3.8 and I can't figure out how I may access the public path to webroot in my views. Previously I could do something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->webroot ?>wp-dist/acd76cde.css" />
```

But when I try this on 3.8 it says:

`Error: webrootHelper could not be found.`

I tried html helper, but can't find a helper method which gives just the public path to webroot. For example `image()` is relative to `webroot/img`, `css()` is relative to `webroot/css` and so on.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

As @ndm said in the comments above, the following works for me as well.

`echo $this->Html->css('lightweight_lpbbd374e3', ['pathPrefix' => 'wp-dist/']);`

**Original my solution, which works too**

`$this->Url->webroot` finally worked for me. So I'm including my css as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->Url->webroot('wp-dist/lightweight_lpbbd374e3.css'); ?>" />
```

Until someone else suggests a better way, I'll continue using this.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, you should be using the HTML helper.

For CSS:

```
<?= $this->Html->css('wp-dist/acd76cde.css'); ?>
```

Just FYI, internally this is using the options defined in `config/app.php`:

```
$pathPrefix = Configure::read('App.cssBaseUrl');
```

So in *theory* if you needed the same paths manually, you *could* read them out of the configs too - but you should just stick with the HTML Helper this is exactly what it's for.

> **From the Docs**:
>
> - https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-css-files
> - https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/html.html#inserting-well-formatted-elements
> - https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/configuration.html#general-configuration

Comment: My problem is my assets are in `webroot/wp-dist/acd76cde.css` and not inside `webroot/css/wp-dist/acd76cde.css`, so `$this->Html->css ` won't work for me.

My assets are generated by webpack, it's a difficult to change the output paths from there due to other requirements.

Comment: If all your assets are in a non-standard directory, just set that in app.config and the Html Helper will use those instead

Comment: @SouvikGhosh A root relative URL (prepend a `/`) or using the `pathPrefix` option (`css('acd76cde', ['pathPrefix' => 'wp-dist/'])`) will work with the `HtmlHelper::css()` method without changing globals.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, guys.

@ndm - Your suggestion works great without changing other files. Updating my answer below with your comment.